# Why my date element is displayed with this format : datetime.date(2018, 6, 30) in MySQL (in terminal)?

Tags: python, mysql, tornado

I use python to insert a date into MySQL. Before I insert the date I changed the date format to:

```
start_datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(stDate), '%Y-%m-%d')
end_datetime_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(enDate), '%Y-%m-%d')

d_stDate= start_datetime_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

d_enDate= end_datetime_object.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

When I use `logging.debug("DATES---->" + d_enDate +'-- '+ d_stDate)`
I get the result as I should in a `%Y-%m-%d` format.

At the moment I'm stuck with `datetime.date(2018, 6, 30)`

Edit:

My query is:

```
cursor1.execute("INSERT INTO "+MYSQL_DB+".events ( `name`, `type`, `startDate`,`endDate`, `location` ) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",[ str(name), str(types), str(d_stDate),str(d_enDate),str(location)])
```

Comment: What exactly are you inserting into the database? Could you please include the query in the question?

Comment: if a db has stored a value as a `date` you will get a `datetime.date` from the python DBAPI. it's actually very handy to have it in this format as it allows you to easily perform date calc/manipulations

Comment: i can use the format as i want despite the fact that its `datetime.date` ? my aim is to populate a json file.

Comment: Where exactly do you get `datetime.date...`? When looking at the values in the database using some database viewer, or when querying the database from Python code again?

Comment: @deceze the date values are coming from my calendar website. I send the date with `var d2 = new Date(endDate)`

`var stDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', d);`

Comment: Not what I asked. You're saying "my date element is displayed [as] datetime.date... in MySQL". Please clarify the *"in MySQL"* part. Where exactly are you checking and seeing that value?

Comment: @deceze i use logging.debug( myjsonfile) and i get the result in the terminal.
Where every startDate and endDate is with the format i mentioned above.

Comment: What is `myjsonfile` now?! That came out of left field all of a sudden.

Comment: i fetchall() after the insert, with a SELECT * FROM "+MYSQL_DB+".events, i store the results in a dictionary and then i use logging.debug() to view the result in the terminal.

Comment: So, when you fetch `DATE` values from the database, the Python MySQL API gives you `datetime.date` objects. That's a rather different question. And has been addressed in the second comment by aydow above.

Comment: Yes i noticed that he mentioned what happened but i still don't understand why it happened, and my question was "i can use the format as i want despite the fact that its datetime.date ?my aim is to populate a json file"

Comment: The "issue" is that whatever database API you're using is automatically translating MySQL `DATE` columns into Python `datetime.date` objects. Why not, they're distinct types in both systems with useful properties, why should you have to deal with just strings? You have two choices: format that `datetime.date` object again when you want to use it, or somehow tell your database API to give you strings instead of objects. If you need help with that latter one we need to know more about your MySQL API.

Comment: @deceze Thank you sir, i think i understood what is going on, i will try to use this date format and if i stumble into any issues i will format it again. Hopefully i won't tho. Also, next time i will be more specific with my questions:)